# Best replacement for this faulty inductor from a computer power supply?

Tags: power-supply, inductor

Edit: Looks like replacing the inductor resulted in the same problem, and my newly wound inductor started causing some smoke. :(

I recently acquired a faulty Corsair CX750M Power Supply that makes a burning smell when turned on. I think that this inductor was the culprit and reached temperatures of >120 degrees Celsius, even with no load on the PSU. I measured the resistance of the two coils, both read exactly 0.0 Ohms. I am guessing that the inductor was heating up because it was internally shorted as the ohm reading should have been above 0.

I have read this forum post: https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/890851-corsair-grey-label-cx750m-burning-smell-fault-finding-and-repair/
Which is by another person with the EXACT same problem. He said he replaced it; (I think he manually wound the coil with new wires?), but that also burnt up instantly.

Here is what the inductor looks like. As you can see, the blackened insulation is rubbing off very easily.

[image: Front of Inductor]
[image: Top Indcutor]

I tried searched Digi-Key for a potential replacement according to the dimensions and type of inductor. However, I could not find the exact inductor and I am unsure of what similar inductor I can use as a suitable replacement. I am also unsure what inductance in henries I should get.

I am hoping someone can help me in finding a similar inductor I can get, or maybe replacing the inductor would not fix it because of some underlying PSU circuity flaw?

Any advice is greatly appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Looks toasty! Is nothing else damaged on the board?

Comment: I don't think so. No blown capacitors and the other inductors don't look burnt.

Comment: Do you know in which conditions the inductor started to burn ? I suspect the issue to not only be limited to the inductor, so even if you replace it you will continue to experience troubles with this PSU.

Comment: I agree with @Genorme, the inductor itself is not the culprit. To fix the inductor, get yourself some magnet wire of the same size, count number of turns and winding direction of the existing one, unwind it and wind with new wire.

Comment: Ok, I will get some magnet wire and try to rewind the inductor.